# navigationController rules doesn't work on ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

My problem is with the `navigationController` the rules just don't apply.

[image]

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationBarColor()
}

func navigationBarColor() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.91, green:0.04, blue:0.51, alpha:1.0)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    }
```

Here's the result - The color is not there

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Is that viewDidLoad in Profile?

Comment: "the rules just don't apply" - this is the most vague description of a problem I've seen in a long time. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Check the newest update

Comment: What you want to try to achieve?  you added image on navigation bar??

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code setting the style properties looks correct. It's likely that `navigationController` is nil.

A better approach is to use a custom navigation controller subclass and connect it to the navigation controller in Interface builder.

```
open class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you set bartintColor and after that
you set the "clear image" in navigation bar :)
of course it is be transparent.

you need image with some color or create it in code: (for example)

```
extension UIImage {

class func imageWithColor(_ color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return UIImage()
    }

    context.setFillColor(color.cgColor);
    context.fill(rect);

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

and set image in navigation bar like this:

call this navigationBar changes when controller will appearing

```
    func updatenavigationBar() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(color), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking based on the question but if you are trying to change the color of the navigation bar I would suggest changing 
:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.91, green:0.04, blue:0.51, alpha:1.0)
```

To:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.91, green:0.04, blue:0.51, alpha:1.0)
```

This will add the color as the background color instead of just the tint color.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
import Foundation
    import Swift

    extension UINavigationController
    {
        func setMainTopNavigationBarAttribute() -> Void
        {
            self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
            self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
            self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
```

You can use this way

```
 let navigationController = UIStoryboard.user.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MMNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
 navigationController.setMainTopNavigationBarAttribute()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You just change this two line in your function


func navigationBarColor() {

navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.91, green:0.04, blue:0.51, alpha:1.0)

//change this two line in your function
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage.init(named: "")
       navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: ""), for: .default)
    }
```